# Course of action for comments requesting external resources?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have had this situation occur a couple times over the past few months, and each time I have had no idea how to handle it.

From the Help Center  (emphasis mine):

> **Questions** asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...

These types of questions are particularly easy to spot. However, as it's written, this guideline only applies to *questions*. Lately, I have seen comments akin to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411435/multiple-login-forms-on-one-page#comment37766056_24412449) asking directly for a tutorial or a link to an external resource, even though the poster has given a *more* than adequate answer to the question. (The OP seems to just be looking for code to be written for him, at least from my perspective.)

Since there's no such thing as "closing" a comment, **how should one go about handling requests to find off-site resources in the comments of a question *or* answer?**

Comment: You *could* flag the comment as noise, but I'm not sure it's necessary. We can live with a few comments requesting external resources.

Comment: If the question and answer were of acceptable quality but the OP wanted a tutorial to better understand then I don't see anything wrong with that. I have given links to tutorials in comments on my answers when I suggest something that the OP wants but they want more detail on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with comments asking for more general pointers (so long as it's within the general topic of the question/answer). It's up to whoever wishes to comment to provide such additional information. There is no incentive to do so since you can't gain additional reputation by providing a quick additional pointer in a comment, so this practice is unlikely to get out of hands.

Such requests in comments are just the symptoms of some of the tensions between the theoretical aims of SO and the way it works.

The knowledge on SO stems from questions. Those questions generally come from problems faced by the users asking the question, because they don't know enough about what they're trying to do.

If the user is blocked because of an error message he or she doesn't understand, that can become a good question on SO (provided that enough details and context are given). Yet, that error message may be actually very specific to a set of conditions. In modern software development environments, you often need many pieces of the puzzle to work together for the overall system to work properly. It's quite common, especially in a development environment, for errors not only to come from the few lines of code in question, but to the way the general environment is configured (network, OS settings, ... Spring config, ...).

You then get a tension between:

- Questions that focus exclusively on those few lines of code, with a specific error message, stack trace and so on. They're likely to be on topic. Yet, the asker may be trying to do something unnecessarily convoluted, or simply have no idea where to go next.
- Answers are less likely to be useful to a wider audience. In may cases, how to fix your problem depends very much on what you're exactly trying to do and where the system is going to be deployed. SO isn't the place to write entire books.

Of course, you could have wider questions to start with, but those would generally be considered too broad.

It can be useful, both for the asker and other readers, to have a link to a generic tutorial on the topic, considering that other readers may try to approach that field via the same path (and being faced with the same error). For example, there isn't always a clear distinction between a user knowledgeable in the field asking about a specific error (due to a slight change of circumstances he or she might not know about), or a user who has no clue and stumbling upon that same error, just because they're trying something.

I sometimes think the alleged loss of quality on SO (perceived by some at least, when reading Meta.SO) comes from that very problem. There's probably only so many basic programming questions that are both specific and useful to a large number of people. After that, there's a large category of questions that a valid questions, yet it's unclear how generalisable their answers can be.

The nature of SO, which aims to keep each question and its answers as single entity, fairly independent of surrounding context (although questions can be linked together), is both a very good thing for clarity, but also the cause of this problem: it doesn't really lend itself to helping the asker more broadly, to address the possibly large pile of other related problems someone in their positions would typically have, effectively making the answers more useful.

As such, there's definitely no harm in asking for and giving quick link to a more generic tutorial in a comment, since Q&A are generally not the place for a more complete tutorial.

Answer (score -3):

I believe StackOverflow should remove the needs for tutorials.

If the answer is correct, the problem should then be solved, so there should be no need for a tutorial on the same subject. If the comment is on your answer, I'd recommend asking the user what is still unclear about the answer you've given to see if you can clarify it further. If the question is on a completely different topic, just tell them to ask a new question (or link them to one if it's already been asked elsewhere).

Comment: (Personally, and at least in this case,) I don't think there's *anything* wrong with the answer, the user is just requesting something where they can copy/paste code from.

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow should answer questions. Maybe answers should prevent the need for further questions.

Comment: @phd443322 maybe askers should learn to read answers...

Comment: @braiam that always helps, surprising the number of people that don't - or decide the answer is too difficult and ignore it. Really answers should answer substantive questions. Syntax errors (as in why my command doesn't work) should be answered in a way that encourages them to read the description of what they are using.

Comment: "*I believe StackOverflow should remove the needs for tutorials.*" Not really, SO is about asking and answering precise questions. Tutorials are about introducing and teaching a subject or a feature, by establishing a context and following its flow. They're not the same goals at all. Nothing wrong with asking for a more general pointer in a comment after asking help for a specific error within the field.